# Calculating the human carrying capacity for turtle tours?

Tags: literature

I am looking to calculate the human carrying capacity of a leatherback nesting beach in the Caribbean to inform conservation policy on the maximum number of people allowed on turtle tours; yet after an exhaustive search, I have found very little. Could anyone point me towards a research article that could be of assistance?

Comment: The carrying capacity of a species at a given location is the number of individuals of that species that can live at this location. I suppose what you are looking for is rather something like the maximum number of humans that can live at a given location while keeping a carrying capacity for leatherback above a certain level. You might want to rephrase the question